# How to create this image (graphing)

Tags: pgfplots

I want to create a graph with only the first quadrant. The values of x can only go from 0 to 9 and the values of y can only go from 0 to 9. In this graph, I want dots for (2,5), (3,3), (5,2) and (7,1). Above each pair specified I want dots above it. For example, the dots above (2,5) are (2,6), (2,7), (2,8) and (2,9). Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. If you don't have the relevant LaTeX skills a screenshot and a very basic document starting from `\documentclass{...` and ending with `\end{document}` is also sufficient.

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again until you get more rep points.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by "include the image as normal and remove the !"

Comment: If you use the image inclusion button above the question (in the question edit window) it will place a link automatically with a `!` prefixed. If you remove that it becomes a normal link and we can add it for you until you get enough reputation points.

Comment: Is that the picture you intended to upload?

Comment: No, I was following what percusse asked. I don't have any pictures to upload. I could scan an image if my verbal description is not enough but it will take me a while. Tell me if this is necessary.

Comment: Coming back to your original question: you may be interested in `pgfplots` (http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), in particular its section about scatter plots. Perhaps combined with `xmin=0,xmax=9`.

Comment: Thanks for the link Christian, I will be back with you guys soon. I have a meeting with a friend this afternoon.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By tikz -- brute force:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[very thin, color=gray] (0,0) grid (10,10);
  \draw [very thick, -stealth] (0,0) -- (11,0);
  \draw [very thick, -stealth] (0,0) -- (0,11);
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}{
    \draw [thick] (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.2) node [below] {\x};
    }
  \foreach \y in {0,1,...,10}{
    \draw [thick] (0,\y) -- (-0.2,\y) node [left] {\y};
    }
  \foreach \x/\y in {2/5,2/6,2/7,2/8,2/9}{
    \draw [fill=black] (\x,\y) circle (2pt);
    }
  \foreach \x/\y in {3/3,3/4,3/5,3/6,3/7,3/8,3/9}{
    \draw [fill=black] (\x,\y) circle (2pt);
    }
  \foreach \x/\y in {5/2,5/3,5/3,5/4,5/5,5/6,5/7,5/8,5/9}{
    \draw [fill=black] (\x,\y) circle (2pt);
    }
  \foreach \x/\y in {7/1,7/2,7/3,7/4,7/5,7/6,7/7,7/8,7/9}{
    \draw [fill=black] (\x,\y) circle (2pt);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `plot` function of `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[very thin, color=gray] (0,0) grid (10,10);
  \draw [very thick, -stealth] (0,0) -- (11,0);
  \draw [very thick, -stealth] (0,0) -- (0,11);
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10}{
    \draw [thick] (\x,0) -- (\x,-0.2) node [below] {\x};
    }
  \foreach \y in {0,1,...,10}{
    \draw [thick] (0,\y) -- (-0.2,\y) node [left] {\y};
    }
  \draw plot [only marks,mark=*] coordinates {(2,5) (2,6) (2,7) (2,8) (2,9)
                (3,3) (3,4) (3,5) (3,6) (3,7) (3,8) (3,9)
                (5,2) (5,3) (5,4) (5,5)(5,6) (5,7) (5,8) (5,9)
                (7,1)(7,2)(7,3)(7,4)(7,5)(7,6)(7,7)(7,8)(7,9)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Using `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,
                ymin=0,ymax=10,
                grid=major,
                tick align=outside,
                xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
                ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}]
\addplot+[only marks]
coordinates {(2,5) (2,6) (2,7) (2,8) (2,9) 
                (3,3) (3,4) (3,5) (3,6) (3,7) (3,8) (3,9)
                (5,2) (5,3) (5,4) (5,5)(5,6) (5,7) (5,8) (5,9)
                (7,1)(7,2)(7,3)(7,4)(7,5)(7,6)(7,7)(7,8)(7,9)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You don't really need any additional packages for such a plot, this is well within the capabilities of the base LaTeX format.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{c}
\begin{document}
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}


\begin{picture}(11,11)(-1,-1)
\thicklines
\put(-.2,0){\line(1,0){10.2}}
\put(0,-.2){\line(0,1){10.2}}
\thinlines
\multiput(0,-.2)(1,0){11}{%
\line(0,1){10.2}\makebox(0,0)[t]{\thec\stepcounter{c}}}
\setcounter{c}{0}
\multiput(-.2,0)(0,1){11}{%
\makebox(0,0)[r]{\thec\stepcounter{c}}\line(1,0){10.2}}

\multiput(2,5)(0,1){5}{\circle*{.2}}
\multiput(3,3)(0,1){7}{\circle*{.2}}
\multiput(5,2)(0,1){8}{\circle*{.2}}
\multiput(7,1)(0,1){9}{\circle*{.2}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just 4 fun with the mix of PSTricks and PGF.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(10,10)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-0.5,-0.5)(9.5,9.5)
\foreach \x/\s in {2/5,3/3,5/2,7/1}{\foreach \y in {\s,...,9}{\psdot[linecolor=blue](\x,\y)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Animated version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x/\s in {2/5,3/3,5/2,7/1}{\foreach \y in {\s,...,9}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-1,-1)(10,10)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-0.5,-0.5)(9.5,9.5)
\pscircle*[linecolor=blue](\x,\y){3pt}
\end{pspicture}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are naughty! Very naughty!

Comment: @HarishKumar: Mission accomplished: [The top investor](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/65683/top-investors)

Comment: Oho Now I see your goal! `:-)`

Answer (score 6):

This solution addresses two different and unrelated issues of the question.

### 1. The Given Data:

If I read the question correctly, the requirements are that the data is:

1. `x` can only go from `0` to `9`, and the values of `y` can only go from `0` to `9`.
2. The given data points are the lower bounds: `(2,5)`, `(3,3)`, `(5,2)` and `(7,1)`.

and that the points referred to as being *above* these points are to be determined. That is the *above* points are **not** part of the data.

So, this solution provides a way of using just the given data:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{plot.dat}
    2,5
    3,3
    5,2
    7,1
\end{filecontents*}
```

and computing the *above* points.

### 2. A New Plot Method:

Well, since the others covered the *usual* drawing methods of `pgfplots`, `tikz` and `pstricks` and even the *esoteric* `picture` environment, I had to find yet another way to do that plot. And I found one: using the `dataplot` package from [the `datatool` bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool).

But this method could certainly be applied to using the other methods of plotting.

---

So, given the above input data we obtain (points in blue show the given data, and the points in red is the extrapolated data).

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{plot.dat}
    2,5
    3,3
    5,2
    7,1
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{dataplot}
\usepackage{pgffor}

% Specify the constraints
\newcommand*{\YMax}{9}
\newcommand*{\YMin}{0}
\newcommand*{\XMax}{9}
\newcommand*{\XMin}{0}

% Temp variable
\newcounter{StartYValue}

\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={xData,YData}]{myPlotData}{plot.dat}

% Now that we have the db read in, we need to create 
% a db with all the points "above" these.
\DTLnewdb{myPlotDataAbove}
\DTLforeach{myPlotData}{\x=xData,\y=YData}{%
    \setcounter{StartYValue}{\y}
    \stepcounter{StartYValue}
    \foreach \YAbove in {\arabic{StartYValue},...,\YMax} {%
        \dtlexpandnewvalue
        \DTLnewrow{myPlotDataAbove}
        \DTLnewdbentry{myPlotDataAbove}{xData}{\x}
        \DTLnewdbentry{myPlotDataAbove}{YData}{\YAbove}
    }%
}

% Now plot the two db that we have.

\DTLplot{myPlotData,myPlotDataAbove}{%
    x=xData, y=YData,%
    minx=\XMin, maxx=\XMax, miny= \YMin, maxy= \YMax,
    xticpoints={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    yticpoints={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    marks={\pgfuseplotmark{*},\pgfuseplotmark{*}},
    colors={blue,red},
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

without specifieing the y coordinates because they are known: `y=int(10/x)..9`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,10)
\psframe*[linecolor=blue!8!white!90](9,9)
\psaxes[ticksize=0 9,tickcolor=black!20]{->}(9.5,9.5)
\psforeach{\ix}{2,3,5,7}{%
  \multido{\iy=9+-1}{\numexpr10-10/\ix\relax}{%
    \psdot[linecolor=blue,dotscale=2](\ix,\iy)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

with current `pstricks.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks/

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(10,10)
\psaxes[ticksize=0 9,tickcolor=black!20]{->}(9.5,9.5)
\pgfforeach \x in {2,3,5,7}{%
  \pgfforeach \y in {\numexpr10/\x,...,9}{%
    \psdot[linecolor=blue,dotscale=2](\x,\y)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I think renaming `\foreach` to `\pgfforeach` is not beneficial because (1) it is not consistent, PSTricks' macros should be prefixed by `ps` or `pst`, (2) typing `\foreach` should be shorter than `\pgfforeach`. But inputing `pgffor` by default is of course a good idea.

Comment: foreach is _not_ renamed!

Comment: I meant aliasing with `let`.

Comment: and there are some good reason to do so ...